# Get number of facebook shares/likes for a url from a specific date to a specific date

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am making a campaign in which i specify that i need a number of likes for this week . for eg 500 likes from 3/3/2014 to 3/9/2014 . So i want to get likes/shares done for that url in my website between that date . I know how to get total number of likes/shares and i use the following code for that.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.example.com'
```

But how to get it from a specific date to a specific date ?

Comment: That's not possible using the link_stat table, because you cannot set the timeframes for the query. It would be possible that you schedule this query each day, and calculate the deltas by yourself